# Survey Monkey - Error updating Collector

Tags: c#, .net, patch, surveymonkey

Out of the sudden, our code stopped working and after some checks we found where.

[image: Example using SM's config set for Postman]

Our code is like this:

```
internal async Task CreateNewCollector(string name)
            {
                _new_collector = await (
                    await _client.PostAsyncAs<CollectorDetails>(
                        _survey.Collectors(),
                        _client.MakeJsonContent(new { from_collector_id = _last_collector.id })
                    ).ContinueWith(n =>
                            _client.PatchAsyncAs<CollectorDetails>(
                                new Uri(n.Result.href),
                                _client.MakeJsonContent(new { name = name, status = "open" })
                            )
                    )
                );
            }
```

It creates a Collector and right after it tries to Patch it to change its name and status. That's when it fails. As mentioned on the image, this is the result:

```
{"error": {"docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes", "message": "Invalid schema in the body provided.", "id": "1002", "name": "Bad Request", "http_status_code": 400}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Survey Monkey support and Amanda (a Technical Support Engineer) guided me through this. I had to change our existing code to, instead of update the collector right after it's been created, add a message to it first and then update. Worked like a charm.